# JS for loop not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a for loop which looks like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
```

It is looping through Firebase data in the database and returning all the data in the database.

However, I want it to only go up to the first 10 database items. So I changed the loop to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
```

But this fails to display any results when the there are less than 10 pieces of data in the database. However, if I set the number to however many objects I have in the database, for example 10 because I have 10 objects, it displays them all. But any less than this number and I just get a blank webpage.

Here is the webpage when I have 10 objects in my Firebase database:

[image]

And here it is when I remove one of those objects:

[image]

I have no idea why this is happening - The logic is correct - if i is less than 9 then display the data - But instead it only displays it when it equals 9.

Here is the full JS:

```js
function refreshUI(list) {
var lis = '';
var lis2 = '';
var lis3 = '';
var lis4 = '';
    for (var i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        lis += '<li data-key="' + list[i].key + '" onclick="addText(event)">' + list[i].book + '</li>';
        lis2 += genLinks(list[i].key, list[i].book)
      };
      for (var i = 10; i < list.length; i++) {
        lis3 += '<li data-key="' + list[i].key + '" onclick="addText(event)">' + list[i].book + '</li>';
        lis4 += genLinks(list[i].key, list[i].book)
      };
        document.getElementById('bookList').innerHTML = lis;
        document.getElementById('bookList2').innerHTML = lis2;
        document.getElementById('bookList3').innerHTML = lis3;
        document.getElementById('bookList4').innerHTML = lis4;
    };

function genLinks(key, bkName) {
var links = '';
links += '<a href="javascript:del(\'' + key + '\',\'' + bkName + '\')"><img src="images/bin.png" style="width: 24px; height: 24px; transform: translateY(-7px); opacity: .4;"></img></a> ';
return links;
};

function del(key, bkName) {
var response = confirm("Are certain about removing \"" + bkName + "\" from the list?");
    if (response == true) {
        // build the FB endpoint to the item in movies collection
        var deleteBookRef = buildEndPoint(key);
        deleteBookRef.remove();
        }
    }

function buildEndPoint (key) {
return new Firebase('https://project04-167712.firebaseio.com/books/' + key);
}
// this will get fired on inital load as well as when ever there is a change in the data
bookList.on("value", function(snapshot) {
var data = snapshot.val();
var list = [];
    for (var key in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            book = data[key].book ? data[key].book : '';
        if (book.trim().length > 0) {
            list.push({
            book: book,
            key: key
            })
        }
    }
}
// refresh the UI
refreshUI(list);
});
```

If anybody has any help I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Try this `pseudocode`: if your list length is bigger than 9 then fetch just 10 elements, if not use list.length as your threshold(that way you do not have the index out of range exception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the list size is shorter than 10, you will get an error in the loop because you will eventually address a property (like `key`) that does not exist on `list[i]` (since it is `undefined`). If you would check the console, you would notice that this error is reported.

To fix this, change the condition of the first `for` loop like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(10, list.length); i++) {
```

This way, the loop will never iterate to an entry that does not exist. It will stop after 9 or after `list.length-1` whichever comes first.

Alternatively, you can just put the two conditions with an `&&` operator:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10 && i < list.length; i++) {
```